# How to format text in flex TextArea?

Tags: apache-flex, textarea, tablelayout

TextArea in flex doesn't render `<TABLE></TABLE>`.

I want to display text in textarea in two columns.

```
Column1           Column2
Row1:             Data, data, data row1
Row2 longer:      Data, data, data row2
```

Depending on text width in Column1 text in Column2 will be shifted. So all rows in Column2 are going to be aligned. How can I do this without html `<table>`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand you the right way, but why not just use raw text and insert fixed number of space between datas?

Comment: I also want Column1 to be bold and I don't want to use monospace fonts. For now I'm using Tabs \t but it would be nice to have auto columns alignment.

Answer (score 0):

TextArea is only good enough to render normal text with little formatting like font/color/indents etc. htmlText support in flash/flex is very limited.

You can use the [**DataGrid**](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/DataGrid.html) control in Flex to render tabular data.

Comment: I want to be able to select text and copy.